# Why does PWA caching not work on webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web, webview-flutter

I Have a PWA website but i wanted it on a mobile app so that i can add it the the play store but while using it on webview flutter the web pages are not being cached it shows "page cannot be reached" without an internet connection.

When i open it first it works just fine but if i close the application and then restart it without an internet connection that's when it doesn't work

Note: this is an already live project that is in production everything works just fine on regular browsers including the install on android and iOS

Comment: Hi there. You need to add more info. What have you done so far to make your app a PWA ?

Comment: I think i have done everything i have made the sw.js, manifest.js etc its basically a live PWA project that is already working i just want to add it to a webview and then put it on play store.

The issue is, when i close the app and open it all over again it does not work without an internet connection